# appium server-side error: xcodebuild failed with code 65

Tags: ios, webdriver, appium

`appium` verion: `1.13.0`

I have `iphone` real device, `ios` version `13.1` and when i try to install my application using this capabilities:

```
{
  "udid": "95bce4567740508a3de73283a5620c8eb9db5d118",
  "platformName": "ios",
  "platformVersion": "13.1",
  "app": "/Users/app.ipa",
  "xcodeOrgId": "BX3P2D4G47",
  "newCommandTimeout": "300",
  "autoGrantPermissions": true,
  "deviceName": "iPhone 7",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "useNewWDA": true
}
```

I got this error:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild
>   failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message:
>   2019-09-25 11:07:59.703 xcodebuild[5160:43162] Error writing xctestrun
>   file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder
>   “WebDriverAgentRunner_iphoneos13.0-arm64.xctestrun” doesn’t exist."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/WebDriverAgentRunner_iphoneos13.0-arm64.xctestrun,
>   NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f836c7fa120 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}} ** TEST
>   BUILD FAILED ** 2019-09-25 11:07:59.754 xcodebuild[5160:43141]
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test
>   session to:
>   /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019.09.25_11-07-59-+0300.xcresult/Staging/2_Test/Diagnostics/WebDriverAgentRunner-C9D2E30A-A644-46F4-AEBD-114C2CA689AF/WebDriverAgentRunner-DAE75DFA-F856-4621-BB6C-F2D6213F5F0A/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019-09-25_110759-ixovOa.log
>   2019-09-25 11:07:59.755 xcodebuild[5160:43104] [MT]
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (1D5447AC-F596-4529-8791-95E89065BD51)
>   Beginning test session
>   WebDriverAgentRunner-1D5447AC-F596-4529-8791-95E89065BD51 at
>   2019-09-25 11:07:59.755 with Xcode 11A420a on target ?? { deviceSerialNumber:
>   F17T7BU4HG7G identifier: 95bce455af0508a3de73283a5620c8eb9db5d118
>   deviceClass: iPhone deviceName: Evgeniy’s iPhone deviceIdentifier:
>   95bce455af0508a3de73283a5620c8eb9db5d118 productVersion: 13.1
>   buildVersion: 17A844 deviceSoftwareVersion: 13.1 (17A844)
>   deviceArchitecture: arm64 deviceTotalCapacity: 26957225984
>   deviceAvailableCapacity: 22861582336 deviceIsTransient: NO ignored: NO
>   deviceIsBusy: NO deviceIsPaired: YES deviceIsActivated: YES
>   deviceActivationState: Activated isPasscodeLocked: NO deviceType:
>   
>   supportedDeviceFamilies: ( 1 ) applications: (null)
>   provisioningProfiles: (null) hasInternalSupport: NO hasWritableSystem:
>   NO isSupportedOS: YES bootArgs: (null) nextBootArgs: (null) connected:
>   YES isWirelessEnabled: NO connectionType: direct hostname: (null)
>   bonjourServiceName:
>   88:6b:6e:22:9f:6b@fe80::8a6b:6eff:fe22:9f6b._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.
>   activeProxiedDevice: (null) } (13.1 (17A844)) 2019-09-25 11:07:59.891
>   xcodebuild[5160:43104] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug:
>   (1D5447AC-F596-4529-8791-95E89065BD51) Finished requesting crash
>   reports. Continuing with testing. *** If you believe this error
>   represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at
>   /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019.09.25_11-07-59-+0300.xcresult
>   2019-09-25 11:07:59.939 xcodebuild[5160:43104] [MT]
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.200 elapsed -- Testing started
>   completed. 2019-09-25 11:07:59.939 xcodebuild[5160:43104] [MT]
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
>   2019-09-25 11:07:59.939 xcodebuild[5160:43104] [MT]
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.200 sec, +0.200 sec -- end
>   2019-09-25 11:07:59.940 xcodebuild[5160:43104] Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
>   “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
>   no such file."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7f836ca0ed50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "No such file or directory"}} Test session results, code
>   coverage, and logs:
>   /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019.09.25_11-07-59-+0300.xcresult
>   Testing failed: "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a provisioning
>   profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities
>   editor. WebDriverAgentRunner: WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app
>   encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the test runner.
>   (Underlying error: The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t
>   be opened because there is no such file. The file doesn’t exist.
>   (Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file
>   or directory))) ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED ** Testing started on
>   'Evgeniy’s iPhone'. Make sure you follow the tutorial at
>   https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md.
>   Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if
>   it is installed and reboot the device.

Any seggestions what to do ? 
My `xcode` project build with no error.

Comment: you should hide your TeamID and uuid in your question and logs

Comment: I ran into this error on an M1 mac, and this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/74648543/290784

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `xcodeSigningId` capability, that is the reason i guess. Read about that [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/).
For the beginning add:

```
"xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not writing platformName's value in the correct syntax. Its iOS not ios

```
cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
```

Comment: ill repeat: this is incorrect. platformName capability is case insensitive